# MS Access text delimiters - Quotations issue

Tags: ms-access, text, vba, csv

I have a problem with a .csv file I am trying to load into Access. There are thousands of threads on this topic, and I have tried to find what I am looking for, but no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am receiving a system-generated csv file, which has 2.5m rows, hence I cant load into Excel, so am using Access.
The file is pipe-delimited, with quotation marks as text identifiers.

My question is this - some fields in the csv are blank, which is expected. However, Access doesn't seem to like the resulting double-quotation marks.

**Example - row which exports correctly (headings and data):**

```
BALANCE_CLASS|BUSINESS_DATE|BIC_CODE|COUNTRY_CODE
"Gross"|"31-Mar-15"|"51"|"LU"
```

**Example - row which gets "Unparsable record" error:**

```
BALANCE_CLASS|BUSINESS_DATE|BIC_CODE|COUNTRY_CODE
"Gross"|"31-Mar-15"|""|"GB"
```

This is an entry where the `BIC_CODE` is blank in the source system database.

Comment: that's because access "escapes" quotes by doubling them.

Comment: is there any way around it?

Comment: pre-process the csv and do string replacements: `|""|` -> `||`?

Answer (score 1):

Use null instead of simply using ""